# Spring WebClient toEntityList not working for List<String>

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-webclient

I have a REST endpoint that returns a simple JSON array of string IDs:

```json
["D0000019","D0000017","D0000016","D0000013","D0000009","D0000020"]
```

The response has `Content-Type: application/json`.

I'm consuming it from a Spring `WebClient`, and am trying to generate a `List<String>` using the `toEntityList` method:

```java
ResponseEntity<List<String>> response = webClient.get()
    .uri("/myEndpoint")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .retrieve()
    .toEntityList(String.class)
    .block();
```

However, rather than properly parsing the JSON, this returns a list with a single item, and that item is the literal string content of the response as shown above.

This same pattern has worked fine for list item types other than `String` (typically, JSON objects).

Is there a way to tell Spring to please parse the response as the JSON that it declares itself to be?

Comment: I am simulating this and also getting the same (incorrect) treatment of the array as a single String. I would like to investigate further. Could you possibly put the Java signature of the method serving /myEndpoint? In particular, what is it returing? Mono<String[]> or Flux<String> or?

Comment: @JohnWilliams - it's returning a Jackson `JsonNode`. The service side of it is just treating it as an opaque blob of JSON. But, the value should in practice always be a JSON array - and I've verified that the response does contain the expected JSON text, and the `Content-Type` is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [rstoyanchev's comment on the issue "WebClient decodes string array as one string"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24734#issuecomment-601139551) this behaviour is intentional.

> This is described here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-jackson.
>
> There is an ambiguity with String and "application/json". It could be a serialized JSON text or a JSON array. We treat it as the former for several reasons. One because you can resolve the ambiguity with a target of Mono<List> whereas the other way around there would be no option. Two because it avoids other issues with SSE streams. Three because JSON Strings are less common and a slightly less longer syntax seems acceptable.

[bringyou mentions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24734#issuecomment-834318641) this workaround:

```
webClient.get().uri().retrieve().bodyToFlux(String[].class);   // now we get a flux<String[]> which only has one item
webClient.get().uri().retrieve().bodyToMono(String[].class);  // or a mono<String[]>
```

Another solution could be to change your REST endpoint to return a line-delimited list of string IDs instead of a JSON array. According to the [Spring Reactive Jackson JSON documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux/reactive-spring.html#webflux-codecs-jackson), the Jackson decoder supports "any line-delimited JSON format such as NDJSON, JSON Lines, or JSON Text Sequences". If you're using Jackson for your REST endpoint, it might be enough to `accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON)` in your client and add `produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE` to the REST controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add .map to this statement like:

```
ResponseEntity<List<String>> response = webClient.get()
    .uri("/myEndpoint")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .retrieve()
    .toEntityList(String.class)
    .map(list -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(list))
    .block();
```